# Getting controller return status code for web api

Tags: c#, .net, api, wep

I am writing a record with the OnActionExecuting method, how can I get the status code of the request

```
LogActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
        {

            _stopwatch.Stop();

            var controller = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
            var action = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];
            var url = filterContext.Request.RequestUri;
            var Method = filterContext.Request.Method;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
            var statusCode = //get status code 
            var req_txt = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var requestResponseModel = new RequestResponseModel()
            {
                /* Url = request.Url.LocalPath.ToString(),
                 Method = request.HttpMethod,
                 Ip = request.UserHostAddress,
                 RequestDate = DateTime.Now,
                 Expires = response.Expires,
                 RequestParams = req_txt,
                 ContentType = request.ContentType*/

            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { id = '2', sifre = 'c' });

            //write string to file
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Tmp/jsondata.txt"), json);


            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OnActionExecuting` is executed before the action is run. The status code does only provide meaningful information after the action is run. Even if there is a response object available that you could get the status code from, the real status code is only available
Therefore, you could use the `OnActionExecuted` method to access the status code that was set by the action.

For details, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs#the-base-actionfilterattribute-class). Though this link describes the behavior of filters for MVC, the basic mechanism is the same for the filters in Web API.

Comment: Please help for web api. Not for MVC

Comment: The classes that are used differ, but the basic behaviour is the same. So the rest of the answer also applies to Web API. I annotate the link.

Comment: OK, I did it.
so where can i capture the body of the query